# How to Delete all data from a table which contain self referencing foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table which has employee relationship defined within itself.
i.e.

```
EmpID   Name  SeniorId
-----------------------
1         A      NULL
2         B       1
3         C       1
4         D       3
```

and so on...

Where Senior ID is a foreign key whose primary key table is same with refrence column EmpId
I want to clear all rows from this table without removing any constraint. How can i do this?

Deletion need to be performed like this
4, 3 , 2 , 1

How can I do this

**EDIT:**

Jhonny's Answer is working for me but which of the answers are more efficient.

Comment: It's pretty clear that Jhonny's is the most efficient and best answer, I'll leave mine up only to serve as a reminder that sometimes I'm not as clever as I think I am.

Comment: @Larry. Acc to it should be less efficient as it will update all rows first then delete them. Rather than directly deleting. Which operation is more efficient , loop or a query ? Please make me clear . I have no idea about this

Comment: Two set-based commands will likely be faster than running numerous set-based commands inside a loop, even if each command in the latter scenario affects fewer rows.  Actual results may vary by, for example, indexing on the table or number of reference levels; you'll have to test to ensure you have the truly optimal situation.  But Jhonny's "looks" better and is certainly clearer and easier to implement.

Comment: @Larry: I appreciate for your support. thx for explaining.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know if I am missing something, but maybe you can try this.

```
UPDATE employee SET SeniorID = NULL
DELETE FROM employee
```

Comment: He he. Keep it simple! :-)

Comment: I feel like this answer is some profound life lesson :)

Comment: Yup, day after day I'm coming closer to the idea that before thinking ourselves we are searching the web to see others` thinking results... nice answer by the way :D

Answer (score 3):

If the table is very large (cardinality of millions), and there is no need to log the DELETE transactions, dropping the constraint and TRUNCATEing and recreating constraints is by far the most efficient way.  Also, if there are foreign keys in other tables (and in this particular table design it would seem to be so), those rows will all have to be deleted first in all cases, as well.

Normalization says nothing about recursive/hierarchical/tree relationships, so I believe that is a red herring in your reply to DVK's suggestion to split this into its own table - it certainly is viable to make a vertical partition of this table already and also to consider whether you can take advantage of that to get any of the other benefits I list below.  As DVK alludes to, in this particular design, I have often seen a separate link table to record self-relationships and other kinds of relationships.  This has numerous benefits:

- have many to many up AND down instead of many-to-one (uncommon, but potentially useful)
- track different types of direct relationships - manager, mentor, assistant, payroll approver, expense approver, technical report-to - with rows in the relationship and relationship type tables instead of new columns in the employee table
- track changing hierarchies in a temporally consistent way (including terminated employee hierarchy history) by including active indicators and effective dates on the relationship rows - this is only fully possible when normalizing the relationship into its own table
- no NULLs in the SeniorID (actually on either ID) - this is a distinct advantage in avoiding bad logic, but NULLs will usually appear in views when you have to left join to the relationship table anyway
- a better dedicated indexing strategy - as opposed to adding SeniorID to selected indexes you already have on Employee (especially as the number of relationship types grows)

And of course, the more information you relate to this relationship, the more strongly is indicated that the relationship itself merits a table (i.e. it is a "relation" in the true sense of the word as used in relational databases - related data is stored in a relation or table - related to a primary key), and thus a normal form for relationships might strongly indicate that the relationship table be created instead of a simple foreign key relationship in the employee table.

Benefits also include its straightforward delete scenario:

```
DELETE FROM EmployeeRelationships;
DELETE FROM Employee;
```

You'll note a striking equivalence to the accepted answer here on SO, since, in your case, employees with no senior relationship have a NULL - so in that answer the poster set all to NULL first to eliminate relationships and then remove the employees.

There is a possibly appropriate usage of TRUNCATE depending upon constraints (EmpployeeRelationships is typically able to be TRUNCATEd since its primary key is usually a composite and not a foreign key in any other table).

Answer (score 1):

Inside a loop, run a command that deletes all rows with an unreferenced EmpID until there are zero rows left.  There are a variety of ways to write that inner DELETE command:

```
 DELETE FROM employee WHERE EmpID NOT IN (SELECT SeniorID FROM employee)

 DELETE FROM employee e1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM employee e2 WHERE e2.SeniorID = e.EmpID
```

and probably a third one using a JOIN, but I'm not familiar with the SQL Server syntax for that.

Comment: @Larry: Thx for answering. I think this answer is considering only two level of senior. Plz check my comment at DVK's answer for more details

Comment: That's why you have to do it in a loop until there are no rows left.  But Jhonny's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to normalize this by splitting out "senior" relationship into a separate table. For the sake of generality, make that second table "empID1|empID2|relationship_type".

Barring that, you need to do this in a loop. One way is to do it:

```
declare @count int
select @count=count(1) from table
while (@count > 0)
BEGIN
    delete employee WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (select 1 from employee 'e_senior' 
        where employee.EmpID=e_senior.SeniorID)
    select @count=count(1) from table
END
```

Comment: organization structure is not defined hence we cant normalize. even 1 senior can have its senior and so on. i.e. A's senior B, B's Senior C, C's Senior D and so on

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why not, by anyway, I added a second method

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM employee;
```

Comment: This won't work in general. Consider a table foo, with a column `id` and another column `parent_id` which is a foreign key on the `id` column. If you have two records A: [`id` = 1, `parent_id` = 0], and B: [`id` = 2, `parent_id` = 1], trying to delete both records at the same time would fail if deletion of A was attempted before deletion of B (because B holds the constraint on A). The accepted answer is the best way - set `parent_id` to NULL for all concerned records and then delete.

Comment: If that is so then the people writing that DBMS should learn some things about the relational model.  "Whenever an
SQL-statement is executed, every constraint whose mode is immediate is checked, at a certain point after any
changes to SQL-data and schemas resulting from that execution have been effected, to see if it is satisfied." as the SQL standard has it.  The updating is set-level and the constraint checking must happen after the "changes have been effected".