# How can I Delete row from table with self reference foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to delete rows from a table. this table has the distinction of being one column primary key and another on the same table being foreign key. Do not ask me why it's like that, because like you I think it's a design flaw. The goal is, to remove records from this table, prior to a certain date using a pl/sql procedure. Below my way to proceed

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE purgeEvenement(annee IN VARCHAR2) IS-- "

          eve_child_id_to_delete DBMS_SQL.Number_Table;-- "
         BEGIN-- "
            SELECT e.eve_child_id  BULK COLLECT INTO  eve_child_id_to_delete from evenement e where EXTRACT(year from e.eve_d_date_heure_event)<annee;-- "
            FORALL i IN eve_child_id_to_delete.first..eve_child_id_to_delete.last-- "
             DELETE FROM evenement e-- "
             WHERE e.eve_child_id = eve_child_id_to_delete(i);-- "
             COMMIT;--"
            DELETE FROM evenement e  where EXTRACT(year from e.eve_d_date_heure_event)<annee;-- "
            COMMIT;-- "
        END;-- "
```

But I have this error

```
ORA-02292: violation de contrainte (EMM_INT.EVE_FK_EVE_CHILD) d'intégrité - enregistrement fils existant
ORA-06512: à "EMM_INT.PURGEEVENEMENT", ligne 5
ORA-06512: à ligne 6
```

I think  is normal because for example if my table has those data:

```
Eve_id (Constraint PK)     EVE_CHILD_ID(Constraints FK)
 1                                  3
 4                                  2
 3                                  1
 5                                  3
```

My pls/sql procedure will failed with the previous  ORA-02292 error.

How can I  delete row where EVE_CHILD_ID =3 for example?

Comment: A self-referencing table isn't necessarily a design flaw. Normally one has a column indicating the *parent* id, though, not the *child* id.

Comment: I think using a lookup table would have been a better choice.

Comment: In the sample data, if you delete the row with `eve_id` = 3, think about what should happen to the rows that have 3 as a value in the column `eve_child_id` (`eve_id` = 1 and `eve_id` = 3). Should those be deleted too? Or should the child value in them be null instead? They can't stay as is, because that violates referential integrity.

Comment: Your sample data isn't consistent as you don't have a PK value of 2. How do you insert new data - is the FK defined as deferrable, and if so is it initially deferred? The full DDL for the table might be helpful.

Comment: Children values  (`eve_child_id`) are deleted too at same time   that `eve_id ` value,  because I want  to avoid orphans rows and avoid to violate referential integrity

Comment: Here is already a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483154/how-to-delete-all-data-from-a-table-which-contain-self-referencing-foreign-key

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Drop the constraint, delete the rows you would like to delete and at the end re-create the constraint. However if you delete a row which was referenced by another rows, you should delete the child rows as well, otherwise you won't be allowed to recreate the constraint at the end of the process.

Comment: Yes indeed it is a solution that I thought. But it is risky to the extent that it could have orphans. What I want to avoid at all costs

Comment: If you are allowed to delete the child rows, delete those first. You can find easily which rows are referenced, simple by using an order by on the id (assuming IDs were incremeted at insertion). But in case you are not allowed to delete the child rows, i'm aftraid there's no way to solve it

Comment: If you look the table give as example in my post, If I try `delete from table where eve_child_id=3` It failed because the primary key of the row is referenced as foreign key in line 3 of my example table. Whose is my problem.

Comment: I see now, there is a cross reference between the rows.. I'm afraid it can be done unless you drop the constraint

Comment: `Drop the constraint, delete the rows and re-create the constraint.` HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `ON DELETE CASCADE`?
Please try add the constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD (
  CONSTRAINT YOUR_TAB_R01 
  FOREIGN KEY (EVE_CHILD_ID) 
  REFERENCES YOUR_TABLE (EVE_ID)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ENABLE VALIDATE)
```

This means that when you delete a record, it will remove all his references.

For example, with this data:

```
Eve_id (Constraint PK)     EVE_CHILD_ID(Constraints FK)
 1                                  3
 4                                  4
 3                                  4
 5                                  3
```

This query: `delete recursive_tab where EVE_CHILD_ID = 3` remove all records that have dependencies with `3`, so `your_table` should look like:

```
    EVE_ID EVE_CHILD_ID
---------- ------------
         4            4
         3            4

2 rows selected.
```